# No operations allowed after statement closed happens when inserting a batch of rows containing large column fields

Tags: mysql, scala, scalikejdbc

I am currently migrating data from a database to another.

For this, I have written a Scala program that uses both Slick and ScalikeJDBC for fetching data from an old database and inserting into a new database respectively.

The problem I am facing now is that when migrating a batch of rows that contain large columns namely `longtext`, the program constantly throws the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed.
```

From observation, when this happens, the CPU utilization goes up as high as almost 100%.
(Throughout the migration process, the utilization hovers around 80%)

What is the correct way to workaround this?

Comment: Please post last 400 lines of your error log after this event so we can see any messages leading to the failure.

Comment: I have found out the cause of this error. It turned out that the database was not handling the requests fast enough and ended up not responding

Comment: Would you like assistance with Global Variable tuning to make the instance perform at a higher rate per second?  View profile, Network profile for contact information, please.